# How to load many text files as separate numpy arrays in a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying generate a numpy array for each 'dat' file (10 in total) using `np.loadtxt`. However, I can't figure out how to store each file in a separate array. Can someone please help me on how to modify the the following code in order to do so?

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('Mydata*.dat'))

for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    
    data = np.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter='\t')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
data = []
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    data.append(np.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter='\t'))
```

Now you have an array filled with 10 numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a dictionary:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('Mydata*.dat'))

data = {}
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    data[filename] = np.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter='\t')
```

Then access the arrays with:

```
data[filename]
```

It might be better to process a bit the filename to only keep a relevant identifier as dictionary key.

```
import re

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('Mydata*.dat'))

data = {}
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    key = re.search(r'Mydata(.*)\.dat', filename).group(1)
    data[key] = np.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter='\t')
```

Then only the variable part of your filename will be used as key (e.g. if the filename is `MydataABC123.dat`, the key will be `ABC123`).

```
data['ABC123']
```